# Getting a list of my followers and followed using Instagram API

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get a list of all my followers and everyone I follow on Instagram using the Instagram API. I think that my response is returning null whenever I try to get my followers.

This is the error I get:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

This is in reference to response.data.length

Here's my app.js:

```
window.Instagram = {

    /**
     * Store application settings
     */
    config: {},

    BASE_URL: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1',

    init: function(opt) {
        opt = opt || {};

        this.config.client_id = opt.client_id;
    },

    /**
     * Get a list of popular media
     */
    popular: function(callback) {
        var endpoint = this.BASE_URL + '/media/popular?client_id=' + this.config.client_id;
        this.getJSON(endpoint, callback);
    },

    /**
     * Get a list of recently tagged media
     */
    tagsByName: function(name, callback) {
        var endpoint = this.BASE_URL + '/tags/' + name + '/media/recent?client_id=' + this.config.client_id;
        this.getJSON(endpoint, callback);
    },

    followers: function(callback) {
        var endpoint = this.BASE_URL + '/users/self/follows?access_token=' + this.config.access_token;
        this.getJSON(endpoint, callback);
    },

    getJSON: function(url, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(response) {
                if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(response);
            }
        });
    }
}

Instagram.init({

        client_id: 'CENSORED',
    access_token: 'CENSORED'

});

$(document).ready(function() {

    Instagram.followers(function(response) {
        var $instagram = $('#instagram');
        $instagram.append('<textarea cols="1" rows="' + response.data.length + '">')
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var name = response.data[i].username;
            $instagram.append(name + '&#13;&#10;');
        }
        $instagram.append('</textarea>');
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you know what is the request status? You should be able to see this in the network tab of the developer console.

Comment: status code 200. I'm pretty sure that's a good sign??

Answer (score 1):

Are you in sandbox mode? if so it is expected to get empty response, read documentation about Sandbox mode: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

(Also I noticed you have code for `'/media/popular?client_id='`, the popular API was deprecated as of June 1st 2016, so you probably are using some old Instagram library code. - You need to read updated documentation and re-implement everything)

Comment: I am in sandbox mode, yes. I'm not exactly sure how to exit sandbox mode.

Comment: The popular code is indeed deprecated, but I'm primarily concerned with getting a list of my followers and the users I follow using this API. Thank you so much for the response by the way!

Comment: you have to get your app complete, reviewed by Instagram and if they approve, then you will go to live mode, until then you can only access you and your sandbox users via API, read docs

Comment: Damn, that's a bummer. Anyways, thanks so much for the response!