# How to get my followers list data in instagram

Tags: instagram-api

I am trying to get list of users following me or followed by me on instagram. I have tried the api (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_followed_by) for getting the information but its returning and blank data array with 200 OK status code. Doesn't find out the solution.
Basically I want to gather to create a daily graph from data.
I have created the app for this where I am the admin and also the sandbox user. Other document said in sandbox mode I can access my data information with scope like follower_list but it still return blank data array.
Anyone can help me to solve this out?

Thanks

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407851/instagram-api-how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-people-a-user-is-following-on-ins

Also if you are in sandbox mode and receive empty response this URL will explain why it happens:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496649/getting-a-list-of-my-followers-and-followed-using-instagram-api

Comment: @AndriiPryimak
Thanks, I have tried the same but its not working for me.
Yes app is in sandbox mode, In sandbox mode can I access my followers??
Also I want to create an analytics graph of my own instagram on my third party website where I want to show Instagram followers, Impressions,   Reach, profile view ,conversion and traffic in daily, monthly and annual basis. Is this possible in instagram ??

Answer (score 1):

In Sandbox mode you will see blank data, you will only see your and your sandbox user's data.

If you add one of your followers to sandbox user (and they accept it), then you will just see that user in API response for followers

Answer (score 0):

From Instagram page:

> Starting 10/1/2017, all permissions other than the basic permission
>   will be unavailable to submit for or obtain.

Instagram only approve the basic scope. Check out the new [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/v2.11).

Comment: Using Instagram Graph I can get the followers count for the instagram business account id. But don't think it's possible (yet) for a non business account Instagram user

Comment: @Guus **basic - to read a user’s profile info and media** You can use the basic scope to get the logged in users profile info and media, this also contains posts, followers and following count.

Comment: what I meant was the list of followers with their id, the Instagram `/users/self` endpoint only gives the total  for `follows` and `followed_by`. Endpoint `/users/self/followed-by` needs `follower_list` scope which is not accepted anymore for new applications. Can you point me to the correct endpoint I need to use to get the list of users who follows me?

Comment: @Guus As I mentioned in my answer, the only scope available is the `basic` scope from now on, so it won't be possible to do that. Go check out Instagram Graph API, link is also in my post.

Comment: We're talking about the same conclusion. It isn't possible. With Instagram API it isn't possible either.